# Send Data from Filtered Table via Outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, html-email

I am trying to send Outlook emails to the designated distributors with information about the project and info from a filtered table.

The filter is based on the distributor's name.

```vb
Sub EmailDistro_1()

    Dim xStrFile As String

    Dim xOutApp As outlook.Application
    Dim xMailOut As outlook.MailItem
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xMailOut = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("Distributor").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Cells(2, 2).Value
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Distributor").Range.Copy
        
    With xMailOut
        .Display
        .To = Range("D2").Value
        .Subject = Range("B8").Value & " " & Range("B9").Value & " - " & Range("B11").Value & " Tile RFQ"
        .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:12.0pt'>" & Split(Range("C2").Value, " ")(0) & "," & "<br/>" & vbCrLf & "Can you please provide me with pricing, lead times AND rough freight to Zipcode 21850 (Forklift on site)." & "<br/>" & vbCrLf & "<br/>" & vbCrLf & .HTMLBody
    End With
    
    Set xMailOut = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

How I want the email to populate.
[image: Photo 1 is how I want the email to populate]

The Excel sheet I am working off of.
[image: Photo 2 is the excel sheet I am working off of.]

Answer (score 0):

Be aware to get the signature added to the message body, you need to call the `.Display` method before dealing with the `HTMLBody` property in the code.

You can use the Word object model and deal with the message body represented in Word as a Document instance, so you could simply use the `Paste` method to insert the copied data in Excel.  The `WordEditor` property returns the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What issue do you have?

Comment: See my other "answer". I am new to Stack; so not sure the etiquette on how to respond to other peoples answers.

Comment: First , there is no need to set the `HTMLBody` property and the Word editor at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully someone else can add some additional assistance here.

Comment: You need to call the `.Display` method before dealing with the `HTMLBody` property in the code.